# Simple REST request to create nodes

Tags: services, 8

I'm having the following issue trying to create nodes from Drupal 7 to a Drupal 6 install. The target Drupal site is running Services 3.x.

Here's my code:

```
$base_url = $params['path'];
$data = array(
  'username' => $params['username'],
  'password' => $params['password'],
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$headers = array();
$options = array(
  'headers' => array('Accept' => 'application/json'),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => $data
);

$response = drupal_http_request($params['path'] . '/user/login', $options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);

// Check if login was successful
if ($response->code == 200) {
  // Now recycle the login cookie we recieved in the first request
  $options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;

  // Create a new node
  $data = array(
    'node' => array (
      'type' => 'cloudnode',
      'title' => 'node1',
      'field_ip_address' => array ('value' => '1.2.3.4'),
    )
  );
  $options['data'] = http_build_query( $data, '', '&');
  $options['method'] = 'POST';
  $response = drupal_http_request($base_url . '/node', $options);
} 
else {
  die ('Failed to login');
}
```

I get a 200 response; the node is being created, but somehow it doesn't take care of my 'field_ip_address' CCK field at all.

I've tried any kind of variations but they don't work. There is not much documentation around as well.

If anyone has succeeded in creating nodes using REST, I would be very interested for any help.

Comment: Not sure if that is your problem, but cck fields are always stored as an array of values. So in your case, it would be something like `'field_ip_address' => array(array('value' => '1.2.3.4')),`. If that's I'll write up an answer, but I'm just guessing right now.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: I think the correct tag here is actually drupal-6 (or maybe both?), because he is creating nodes on the D6 site, so the API must match d6, even if the code runs on a d7 site.

Comment: Exactly !!! That was it ! Thank you very much, you saved my hairs :)

Comment: Would you mind posting your full method for creating a node with CCK fields to this page at drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1070066 Or make a new documentation page, but put it in the new Services 3.0 handbook, which is where that that other page is located.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CCK fields are always stored as an array of fields, even if the actual field is limited to only a single value.

So you it should be something like:

`'field_ip_address' => array(array('value' => '1.2.3.4'))`

Note that in Drupal 7, field values are additionally grouped by the language, which is 'und' ([LANGUAGE_NONE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7)) if the field is language-agnostic. So it would be something like this:

`'field_ip_address' => array('und' => array(array('value' => '1.2.3.4')))`

Copied from my comment, so that the question can be marked as fixed :)

Comment: Will keep that in mind; also do you have any example for rest file upload ?

Comment: No idea :) I suggest you create a new question, someone else might.